# plot_histogram() function in R not working. Please assist?

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a batch histogram visualization from my data in RStudio. Meaning, I want to create a histogram for each variable in my dataframe at once. For some reason I keep getting an error message saying that the plot_histogram() function doesn't exist. Has anyone else had this problem? Could this be a problem with the latest updated version of R? I recently downloaded R version 4.1.1 and have checked for package updates and am still having this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

[plot_histogram() error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uebkj.png)

Comment: Try (re-)installing the `DataExplorer` package with the command `install.packages("DataExplorer")`: this needs to be done every time you install a new major version of R (so, not every time you update R). Then, make sure that you "load" your package with `library(DataExplorer)`.

Comment: Before installing the package, it would be wise to check that you did not just forget to load it : so try the second command first (`library(DataExplorer)`) and see if it returns an error.

Comment: Thank you Vincent. I'm new to R. I thought that plot_histogram() was apart of ggplot2. I didn't even have DataExplorer installed or loaded. Super embarrassing. But perhaps this will help someone else as well. That solved the problem.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the moral of the story is that the name in the upper left hand corner on the RDocumentation website is the package that needs to be installed for a function to work. So if R is saying that the package doesn't exist, install and load that name.

[Package name on RDocumentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXrw5.png)